# why App is Starting with 40 seconds of delay?

Tags: android, delay, android-cardview, mismatch, dex2oat

in my `SplashActivity` I used `retrofit` and `eventbus` .

I must wait for starting retrofit request or maybe starting `APP` at least **40 second** .

before that is just showing a white page.

in each second I get two Log series like this :

```
01-04 09:36:08.104 5217-5217/? W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-04 09:36:08.104 5217-5217/? W/dex2oat: Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) for the command line:
01-04 09:36:08.104 5217-5217/? W/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg & --debuggable --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-features=smp,ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/data/com.idek_2.titrefarsi/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-cardview-v7-25.0.1_1baeb40f31cb26daebad20328eaaeda07318001c-classes.dex --oat-fd=35 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.idek_2.titrefarsi/cache/slice-com.android.support-cardview-v7-25.0.1_1baeb40f31cb26daebad20328eaaeda07318001c-classes.dex --compiler-filter=speed
01-04 09:36:08.106 5217-5217/? I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --debuggable --dex-file=/data/data/com.idek_2.titrefarsi/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-cardview-v7-25.0.1_1baeb40f31cb26daebad20328eaaeda07318001c-classes.dex --oat-fd=35 --oat-location=/data/user/0/com.idek_2.titrefarsi/cache/slice-com.android.support-cardview-v7-25.0.1_1baeb40f31cb26daebad20328eaaeda07318001c-classes.dex --compiler-filter=speed
01-04 09:36:08.618 5217-5217/? I/dex2oat: dex2oat took 514.000ms (threads: 2) arena alloc=259KB (266112B) java alloc=86KB (88464B) native alloc=830KB (850408B) free=1729KB (1771032B)
```

what should I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 this happens before SplashActivity's onCreate() method

Comment: it might be because you app is built for ARM CPU, and your device has x86 CPU. So it has to *translate your app from ARM to x86* when you first launch it

Comment: @VladMatvienko I use Avd and I don't know any setting for building app for specific cpu

Comment: that is only first launch issue, right? so if you run the app 2nd time from the app menu, it starts instantly?

Comment: @VladMatvienko Yes !

Comment: Do you use any native libraries (NDK libs)?

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html

Comment: @VladMatvienko No I don't

Comment: then I think you should try ARM emulator, or real device before declaring a problem

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko would you like to take a look at this bountied question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/58027762/4288782 the issue there seemed to appear right after I removed NDK from the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable Instant run, and also disable deploy in instant run from File -> Settings

Answer (score 0):

In particular, the `Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features` warning - which *could* be causing the delay, can result from the fact that the running emulator has been configured to run with an [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) (e.g. x86, x86_64) for which the native libraries are not available inside the associated APK.

For example, it is possible that the emulator is running one an `x86_64` CPU/ABI and that the APK only includes native libraries for `x86` and (maybe) `armeabi-v7a`.

Checking the emulator's ABI is easy to do using Android Studio:

[image: AVD's dialog in Android Studio]

(here the emulator is a `x86`).

Checking which native libraries' flavors have been included is also easy using Android Studio. Open the APK file by double tapping on it in the Project file-tree view, or drag and drop it from outside. Then, expand the 'lib' part of the content tree:

[image: APK content: lib]

(Here you see that all common ABI's have been included, namely `x86_64`, `x86` and `armeabi-v7a`).

So in order to try to resolve this kind of an issue (this worked for me), you can try to either recreate a proper AVD, or revisit your app's `splits` configuration. This is a typical configuration for a standard, single-flavored APK:

```
android {
    // ...

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable false
            universalApk false
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'x86_64'
        }
    }
}
```

You can control the APK's content in this regard under the `include` part. Be advised, however, that without splitting the APK its overall size increases.

If you have more complex APK splitting configuration, you can still get this result, but better refer to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html) first.