# Installing app takes minutes with dex2oat warnings

Tags: android, android-studio, dex, android-multidex, dex2oat

I have re-opened an Android Studio project after quite some time, and I'm seeing fast builds as usual, but now the "Install" step from Android Studio (3.5) is taking minutes, while it used to take seconds.

If I open the device Logcat while installing, I can see a huge amount of these:

```
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.onViewCreated(android.view.View, android.os.Bundle)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.onViewModelCreated()
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.removeCancelListener(com.package.base.view.BaseDialog$CancelListener)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.removeDismissListener(com.package.base.view.BaseDialog$DismissListener)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.setChildFragmentInjector(dagger.android.DispatchingAndroidInjector)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.setSharedValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.setViewModelFactory(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: dagger.android.AndroidInjector com.package.base.view.BaseDialog.supportFragmentInjector()
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 647(112KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 60us total 250.774ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 446(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 60us total 252.704ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 396(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 67us total 257.367ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 413(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 68us total 258.540ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 413(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 64us total 253.988ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 413(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 61us total 258.701ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 413(13KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 60us total 255.313ms
I/dex2oat: Explicit concurrent copying GC freed 419(45KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 12MB/18MB, paused 60us total 261.034ms
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseFragment.<init>()
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseFragment.applyStatusBar(com.package.base.view.BaseFragment$StatusBar)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseFragment.dispatchOnStatusBar()
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseFragment.restoreStatusBar(android.app.Activity)
W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once: void com.package.base.view.BaseFragment.saveStatusBar(android.app.Activity)
```

All methods seem to be processed twice (at least) and the garbage collector seems to be doing a lot of work.

I don't know what happened, but I would love to have this fast as it was - right now developing is impossible. Can anyone help?

### Extra info

Before dex2oat starts this very long process, I can see the following logs:

```
W/dex2oat: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/dex2oat: Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: -ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-popcnt) for the command line:
W/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=8 --zip-location=base.apk --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --oat-fd=9 --oat-location=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA==/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=quicken --swap-fd=11 --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
I/dex2oat: /system/bin/dex2oat --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --compiler-filter=quicken --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
I/dex2oat: Large app, accepted running with swap.
```

### Build file

This is part of `build.gradle` for the app module. This is a multi-module project, but the other files are very similar.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion(AndroidBuild.compileSdk)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.package"
        minSdkVersion(AndroidBuild.minSdk)
        targetSdkVersion(AndroidBuild.targetSdk)
        versionCode = 7
        versionName = "0.2.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        renderscriptTargetApi = 24
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled = true
        multiDexEnabled = true

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunnerArgument("clearPackageData", "true")
    }

    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            // signing stuff
        }
    }

    testOptions {
        // execution = "ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            isShrinkResources = true
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFile(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-defaults.txt"))
            proguardFile("proguard-rules.pro")
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            versionNameSuffix = "-debug"
            // Hoping that this should speed up builds due to multidexing
            defaultConfig.minSdkVersion(21)
        }
    }

    dataBinding.isEnabled = true
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

### aapt output when using vmSafeMode="true"

Output when running `./Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/29.0.2/aapt list -a app-debug.apk` is huge, pasting only the relevant part:

```
E: application (line=57)
  A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f11014c
  A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f100002
  A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f0e0001
  A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.package.App" (Raw: "com.package.App")
  A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
  A: android:allowBackup(0x01010280)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
  A: android:vmSafeMode(0x010102b8)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
  A: android:supportsRtl(0x010103af)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
  A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
```

Comment: can you put gradle file here?

Comment: What phone and android version are you using? Have you tried another phone?

Comment: @esentsov Tried with a Nexus 5X API 28 and with emulators. It does not seem to be device specific.

Comment: @Mr.AF if you tell me which part you are interested in, I might paste it or simply answer to you. I can tell that this is a MultiDex enabled app, as described here : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex .

Comment: Inside Android tag

Comment: @Mr.AF added in question.

Comment: @natario when do warnings appear? in debug mode or release mode?

Comment: @Mr.AF in debug, haven't checked release, but that doesn't matter too much. What I really need is fast debug builds.

Comment: @JonGoodwin thanks for info! My machine has 16GB . What is swapping? What are you suggesting?

Comment: @JonGoodwin if this is what you are referring to, I have the following in gradle properties: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx3072m`.

Comment: Ah, I just saw you say **"Installing"** while I am talking about **"building"**. The most significant change from **Dalvik** to **ART** is that **Dalvik** is based on Just-in-Time (**JIT**) compilation, while **ART** is based on Ahead-of-Time (**AOT**) compilation, on the device. When you install the new way is to complie on the device. [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) See [Android_Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Runtime). Your old app may be cluttered with unneeded duplicates *processed more than once*: OR your app is too big

Comment: Can you reproduce this if you import your project on a different computer with a clean Android Studio installation? (Use a VM if you don’t have access to another actual computer. Creating a temp user account on your current computer might also be enough.)

Comment: @natario i am researching about your problem. i need to know if you configured ART options ? or did you customized ART utility ?

Comment: @natario and your target mobile's android version .

Comment: @natario i am close to the problem .if my assumption to be true.

Comment: @Mr.AF no ART configuration. compileSdk=29, targetSdk=29, minSdk=18

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

**On device** *cache build* at *install time* (using [dex2oat](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure)) i.e. **after** the app has been built on your build machine:

### dex2oat warnings

This is where the **`W/dex2oat: Method processed more than once:`** warnings are coming from in the [android.googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com) in the file [`verification_results.cc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/0e5e9fd33521d0f9a2cc6551cb77b4b196e82082/compiler/dex/verification_results.cc) method `WriterMutexLock mu()`.

```
  WriterMutexLock mu(Thread::Current(), verified_methods_lock_);
  auto it = verified_methods_.find(ref);
  if (it != verified_methods_.end()) {
    // TODO: Investigate why are we doing the work again for this method and try to avoid it.
    LOG(WARNING) << "Method processed more than once: " << ref.PrettyMethod();
    if (!Runtime::Current()->UseJitCompilation()) {
      DCHECK_EQ(it->second->GetDevirtMap().size(), verified_method->GetDevirtMap().size());
      DCHECK_EQ(it->second->GetSafeCastSet().size(), verified_method->GetSafeCastSet().size());
    }
    // Delete the new verified method since there was already an existing one registered. It
    // is unsafe to replace the existing one since the JIT may be using it to generate a
    // native GC map.
    delete verified_method;
    return;
  }
```

The:

> `// TODO: Investigate why are we doing the work again for this method
>   and try to avoid it.`

is interesting, seems Google know about it, somewhat.

This Info message is also interesting:

> I/dex2oat: Large app, accepted running with swap.

This *suggests* the `dex2oat` has detected a large app, and is going to swap ([swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) is VERY slow, RAM copied to storage, and back again).

## Fixes

### (1) Reduce app size

Slim down your app! See [Reduce your app size](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/reduce-apk-size).

### (2) Disable ART

[ref1](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/disable-android-art-ahead-of-time-compilation-to-optimize-debug-deployment/)
Create a **new** *minimal* `…/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
<manifest
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
 <application android:vmSafeMode="true" />
</manifest>
```

[ref2](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#vmSafeMode)
**android:vmSafeMode**

> Indicates whether the app would like the virtual machine (VM) to
>   operate in safe mode. The default value is "false".
>
> This attribute was added in API level 8 where a value of "true"
>   disabled the Dalvik just-in-time (JIT) compiler.
>
> This attribute was **adapted in API level 22** where a value of "true"
>   disabled the ART ahead-of-time (AOT) compiler. When `vmSafeMode` is
>   set to `true` this process will be executed with the following
>   argument:

### (3) Late manual argument insertion with [adb shell](http://adbshell.com/):

```
/system/bin/dex2oat ... --compiler-filter=interpret-only
```

Your running:

```
 /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=8 --zip-location=base.apk --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --oat-fd=9 --oat-location=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA==/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=quicken --swap-fd=11 --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
```

and:

```
 /system/bin/dex2oat --input-vdex-fd=-1 --output-vdex-fd=10 --compiler-filter=quicken --debuggable --classpath-dir=/data/app/com.package-7KbZxh8JQyXUOcSGvv-5hA== --class-loader-context=PCL[]
```

### (4) Remove tasks

Try to maximise your available RAM at install time by closing unneeded apps (or use something like [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify&hl=en_GB)).

### (5) Try useing [Instant run](https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f)

- Build and deploy only the incremental changes
- Don’t reinstall the app.
- Don’t restart the app.
- Don’t even restart the Activity.

### Debugging

> Another method for determining if `vmSafeMode` is set for a given
>   `APK` is to use the `aapt.exe` tool. You will find the `aapt tool` in
>   the `build-tools` folder of the `Android SDK`, which differs in
>   location based on your chosen OS. You will probably have several
>   different versions installed and will find it in a location such as:

```
.../Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt.exe
```

Execute the list command:

```
aapt list -a myapkfile.apk
```

This should produce output including:

```
Android manifest:
N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
  E: manifest (line=17)
    A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
    A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0" (Raw: "1.0")
    A: package="com.testing.sample.myapp" (Raw: "com.testing.sample.myapp")
    A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x16 (Raw: "22")         <---NOTE
    A: platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727" (Raw: "5.1.1-1819727")
    E: uses-sdk (line=22)
      A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
      A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x16
    E: application (line=26)
      A: android:label(0x01010001)=@0x7f0b0001
      A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f030000
      A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
      A: android:vmSafeMode(0x010102b8)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                       ^
                       |
----------NOTE---------+
```

Comment: I can't reduce my app size - shrinkers and other optimizations act on release builds, but my issue is during development, on debug builds. I'd like to disable dex2oat on debug builds, but the flag to do so is not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116259/4288782 .

Comment: @natario It would be helpful if you included the result of **aapt list -a** *myapkfile.apk* (See my debugging update).

Comment: Added to my question. The vmSafeMode is present, but dex2oat still runs (with swapping, warnings, delay and everything). As if it wasn't set.

Comment: @natario The **A: platformBuildVersionCode** =(type 0x10)0x16 (Raw: "22")  would be useful along with the values of *AndroidBuild.minSdk* and *AndroidBuild.targetSdk* and *compileSdkVersion(AndroidBuild.compileSdk)* in your **build.gradle**. Presumably your using **apply plugin: 'com.android.application'** and not *apply plugin: 'com.android.dynamic-feature'* Have you updated to the *latest* versions of gradle and Android Studio ? What is your phone API ?

Comment: compileSdk=29, targetSdk=29, minSdk=18, Android Studio 3.5, device API is 27 but this does not seem to be device specific. I am using com.android.application indeed.

Comment: A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1d, A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0xa

Comment: That is strange @natario, it should work.See from [issuetracker.google.com](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123331468) **That either means the app needs to be overall small, or you may consider [splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits), as they're compiled separately.** Also [issue 77842465](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77842465) and [123331468](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123331468)

Comment: @natario in case of excessively large resources, put them in a content package.

Comment: I've been able to test vmSafeMode more today. It works on API 24, 25, 26, 28, 29. But on API 27, it has no effect - dex2oat is still running and doing the full job.

Comment: My APK is about 6MB, not a big app really.

Comment: @natari 6MB is small in my opinion. 50-100MB is big. I think it is done on multiple threads, that's why the mutex lock is called so much. Is your Phone short on RAM because you have many services running?

Comment: No, this also happens on a fresh emulator install with basically no apps installed.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what is **`dex2oat`**, it works for `Verifying app behavior on the Android runtime (ART)` for this refer this link

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/verifying-apps-art

> Now as you need to do is to make this process faster for builds

you can disable this **ART(ahead-of-time)** to optimize debug deployment and make faster builds.
by

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   ...>

 <application
 ...
 android:vmSafeMode="true">
 ...
```

> Note:  it is only possible for targetSdkVersion of 22+ and you’re
>   running a device using the ART runtime.

after disabling this it will decrease you build time 
for more you can refere the following link https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/07/03/disable-android-art-ahead-of-time-compilation-to-optimize-debug-deployment/

Comment: I have tried adding this flag, but I get the same behavior - slow Install and all the `dex2oat` logs are still there.

Comment: @natario is it reducing build time  as your need or also taking same time to build?

Comment: It takes the same time, with all the warnings and such

Answer (score -1):

I have something that can help you 
if you are using windows open up terminal window in android studio and type

```
gradlew installDebug
```

or in linux put

```
./gradlew installDebug
```

for more info link here

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Answer (score -1):

Below adjustments could make things faster (I have 8Go ram, adapt to yours):

In ..\android-studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions

```
-Xms2G
-Xmx4G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=580m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
```

In studio.exe.vmoptions

```
-server
-Xms1G
-Xmx2G
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m
```